# Having problems with ip address showing up on my address bar instead of domain wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, dns, migration, amazon-lightsail

I just recently moved my wordpress website from inmotion hosting to aws lightsail. I used all-in-one migration tool to migrate wordpress to new instance I created. I added DNS A-records, MX, TXT and CNAME. I changed nameservers on my Godaddy domain to point to it. If you go to greeksandscholars.store it shows up store I migrated. So my problem is that if I want to log in to my wordpress(on lightsail) I have to use the ip-address/wp-admin but if I try to use mydomain/wp-admin it sends me to my old wordpress site and I see the following screen.

[when I login using domain/wp-admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qra2G.png)

I tried to change the siteURL and homeURL but they show up greyed out. I have gone to wp-config to change it there but last time I did that it gave me a white blank screen. I am bit stumped at this point on what else I need to do to fix this issue.

Comment: Hello, you might want to ask this question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: or: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you add or update your DNS records it takes a couple of hours to reflect. Alternately I feel you may be forwarding your domain to an IP address.